# SSAS m2m relationship without bridge table

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

Example:

We have 2 fact tables:

1. Fact table with pk that include column1 and column2. Also we have measure1.
2. Second fact table have pk just with column2 and one measure2.

Which type of relationship should we use for dimensions in ssas, that have no regular key for relationship with measure2? Should it be m2m? If we use regular type it will multiple measure2 and show wrong information. In fact it is not many to many relationship, case for one row from fact table 1 there is just one row from fact table 2. Could you please explain me?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer, but I can tell you that fact tables do not have relationships to other fact tables.

Comment: I meant relationship between dimension and measure. This example is very simple. 1st fact table has pk with 2 columns, second has pk with 1 cplomn. Dimension have pk with same 2 columns that 1st fact table. What type of relationship should we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dimension table has a 2-column PK, then your fact table must have both of those columns to have a relationship to that dimension.

In the 2nd fact table, you can either add the missing column to the table, or use a view to add it, or even add it in the Data Source View in SSAS as a last resort.

Comment: I know that your variant is workable. In my example second fact table with 1 pk column have anoyher detalization and couldnt have pk with 2 columns. Example: 1st table is table with region and shops. 2nd is table just with region cause in doesnt have shop level.

Comment: Well then it can't accurately relate to the dimension because there's no way to know which shop the facts in that table relate to.   Sounds like you need another dimension that is just region.

Comment: 1st table: region, shop, sales, date. 2nd table: region, population, date. (Very simple example to understand). I can relate dimension date, region, shop and region-shop (with hierarchy) to 1st fact table. Also I can relate all dimension to 2nd table but for shop and region-shop dimension I have use m2m relationship cause I want to see at any level of shop population of region, not sum of population for each shop in region. Is it right to relate shop as m2m for 2nd fact table? It works at all my example, I just want to get some explain, cause there is no bridge table between 1st and 2nd tables

Comment: You can't relate shop dimension to the second fact table, because the 2nd fact table doesn't have shop.

Comment: Yes, is is, but shop can be relate to 2nd table as many to many relationship using 1st fact table.

Comment: There is no way to create this relationship in the SSAS.   The dimension has to relate directly to the measure group.   You can't use Fact Table 1 to help create the relationship between a dimension and Fact Table 2.

Comment: Why does it work? I've create this simple cube and shop dimension related as many to many to 2nd table. It's show correct info at all levels. May be my explanation is hard to understand, I'm sorry. I created a lot of cubes at work, but this example with m2m faced me with dissonance.

Comment: Your explanation is very fuzzy, and I can't tell why it works without seeing what you've done.  If it works, then what is the question?

Comment: Send me ypur mail and I'll send you project with example. Sorry for this explanation.